# Realizing Baumslag-Solitar groups as functions of the $n$-adic integers

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let $\mathbb{Z}_n$ denote the ring of the $n$-adic integers.  I recently read a paper which used the fact that the Baumslag-Solitar groups BS($\pm$1,n) and BS(n,$\pm$1) can be realized as functions $\mathbb{Z}_n \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_n$.  Can BS(m,n) (for m and n arbitrary) be realized as a group of functions $\mathbb{Z}_r \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_r$ for some $r$?  Thanks!

Comment: What sort of functions did you have in mind?  Group automorphisms?  Ring automorphisms?  Continuous?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you mean action by automorphisms, then the answer is "no" since the Baumslag-Solitar groups $BS(m,n)$, $|m|\ne |n|\ge 2$ are not residually finite. The groups $BS(m,n)$ do act nicely on the products of a tree and the Hyperbolic space: http://www.emis.de/journals/JLT/13-2/galpl.ps.gz .

Comment: Should that be $|m| \ne |n| \ge 2$ ?

Comment: Yes, I fixed that. 

Comment: Can these groups act just as functions (not automorphisms)?

Comment: Yes. Every countable group acts faithfully by permutations on every countable (and more than countable) set. 

Comment: Yet another silly rejoinder: should that be "on every infinite countable ..."?

Comment: @Derek: I consider 'countable" to be of cardinality $\aleph_0$. 